# Is there an algorithm which determines whether a given ideal $I$ in a ring $R$ is prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, algorithms

I suspect the answer is no, but I would love for someone to provide a proof or a reference arguing why. I don't know much about the mathematics of showing whether or not there exist algorithms which output certain information, but would love to hear places where I can find out about related problems!

By ring, I mean a commutative ring containing the identity element. I would also appreciate answers for finitely generated $k-$ algebras, i.e. quotients of $k[x_0, ..., x_n]$.

Comment: First of all, what do you mean by "in a ring"? Is it (a quotient of) the polynomial ring?

Comment: I updated my question with the following: "By ring, I mean a commutative ring containing the identity element. I would also appreciate answers for finitely generated $k-$ algebras, i.e. quotients of $k[x_0, ..., x_n]$."

Comment: Maybe Gröbner bases can shed some light. After googling this I came about this post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60957/how-to-determine-whether-an-ideal-is-prime-or-not-by-an-algorithm